# Spring elasticsearch - retrieve document which has largest value in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am looking for an elegant way to retrieve document that has largest value in a certain field of his.
For example, I want to retrieve document that has largest timestamp.
I've tried using aggregations, but it I could not manage to get it working, it would only return a field.
I've also considered using sorting and the fetching the first element, but I find that a bit bruteforce. Such query would something like:

```
  SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 1))
            .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(FIELD_TIMESTAMP)
                    .order(SortOrder.DESC))
            .build();
```

Is there any better way of doing such a task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use size() method of SearchResponse to get the document with highest response.

For your query, it should be like this:

```
FieldSortBuilder timestampSort = SortBuilders.fieldSort(FIELD_TIMESTAMP).order(SortOrder.DESC);

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
            .addSort(timestampSort)
            .setSize(1)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

Above query will return only one document, i.e: first document from your query response.